# Moving out camera view in Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have an activity with toolbar at the bottom of the screen. Toolbar has a camera button. When user clicks the button, there must appear camera view. It must appear from the bottom of this activity, under the toolbar, fill up to 1/3 of the screen. I created SurfaceView for the camera. But can't set it below the toolbar because of

> alignParentBottom="true"

How to do this appearance?

Here are my layouts

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#f4f5f7">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#f4f5f7"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/camera59" />

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using animated LinearLayout.

Camera_Activity.class

```
public class Camera_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton btn_camera;
ImageButton btn_mic;
SurfaceView sv;
LinearLayout show_video;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anim_footer);

    show_video = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.show_video);
    btn_camera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    btn_mic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_mic);
    sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);


    btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sv.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final Animation show = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.show_video);
                show_video.startAnimation(show);
            }
        }
    });

    btn_mic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                final Animation hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.hide_video);
                hide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                show_video.startAnimation(hide);
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

anim_footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/show_video"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80000000">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_mic"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_cat"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_mic"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btn_mic"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <SurfaceView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/photo"
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Animations:

show_video.xml

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_cubic"
android:startOffset="150"
android:fromYDelta="86%"
android:toYDelta="0"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:duration="2000"/>
```

hide_video.xml

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce"
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="85%"
android:duration="1500"/>
```

Comment: Please add some context, link only answers are frowned upon on SO.